# Creating & Management of Electron-like Windows from Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, electron, chromium

**Good day everyone!**

---

I develop a Google Chrome Extension. The architecture is mainly built on using content script in Chrome tab and separate master window for providing basic management and user-oriented information. Extension should provide a good-user-experience and for that I have an appropriate list of criteria:

1. Creating master window in specified width & height, top & left. In some cases creating modal window.
2. Draw attention or focus to the master window for interacting with user.
3. Unresizable.
4. Zoomable by mouse wheel or buttons.
5. Toggle Always-on-Top.

Additional criteria. Extension should work properly out of box. Any tricky additional settings aren't satisfying for end users. Extension should work properly in Chromium-like browsers.

---

The current state of my Extension is that I use the Chrome Extension API's [chrome.windows](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows) for  creating (1) and focusing (2) to the master window, and [chrome.tabs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs) for zoom operations (4).

I know there is a limitation of using unresizable Chrome windows (3). Looks like it's a dead end.

My implementation of Always-on-Top feature (5) documented in chrome.windows is not working. Here's  code I use:

```
chrome.windows.getCurrent({ windowTypes: ['panel'] }, function(window) {
    chrome.windows.update(window.id, { focused: true }, function(w) {
        w.alwaysOnTop = true;
    });
});
```

The console.log says that w.alwaysOnTop is toggled from false to true, but there's no changes, and next call do the same. The accepted answer here [Chrome extension pop up windows always on top](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21385798/chrome-extension-pop-up-windows-always-on-top/23764128) says about Chrome flags, etc, which is not suitable for end users.

---

I have some information about [chrome.app.window](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window), it provides good features. But it seems that the developers will remove support for Chrome Apps. In this article [Transitioning from Chrome Apps](https://developers.chrome.com/apps/migration) is highly recommend to use chrome.windows instead, but again not a word about support for (3) and (5).

---

Using the [Window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) don't make any effect in Chrome Dev 82.0.4056.3. It just do the same as Chrome.windows do. And something tells me that this is not quite a cross-browser solution.

---

On my opinion, the Electron [BrowserWindow](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/browser-window) can do the best with above list of criteria. I know for that Electron combines Chromium and Node.js. But I can't find any more detailed documentation or appropriate examples about this topic.

Also last days I look a bit quickly on React and Angular opportunities. Seems like Angular is more suitable for Google. I'm total new to that frameworks.

---

So, here I am. Any help or clues on this topic will be very helpful for my purpose. Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no solution matching your criteria. You'll have to use a separate utility. Extensions can't create unresizable windows. Setting alwaysOnTop was only available in the past together with the `panels` experiment which was removed a few years ago.

Comment: Thanks! But I still think that somewhere should be the way to create Electron BrowserWindow from the Chrome Extension popup. This is the main question and direction of my thoughts.

Comment: No, there is none.